# How to get the value from<td> and save to Database in php

Tags: php, html, symfony, twig

I have a Table with checkboxes and I want to edit some td and want to get the value. 
Here is my Code

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><input type="checkbox" id="allcb" name="allcb"/> Check all</th>
            <th data-field="id">ID</th>
            <th data-field="firstName">First name</th>
            <th data-field="lastName">Last name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for user in product.users %}
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkBox[]"  id="ic" value="{{ user.id }}" /></td>
                <td  data-title="id">{{user.id}}</td>
                <td data-title="firstName">{{user.firstname}}</td>
                <td data-title="lastName" contenteditable='true' name="v1">{{user.lastname}}</td>

            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>

</table>
if(isset($_POST['checkBox']) && !empty($_POST['checkBox'])&& isset($_POST['v1'])){

         $user =$_POST['checkBox'];
        $v1 =$_POST['v1'];

         $zl = 0;
         foreach ($user  as $id)
         {
           foreach ($v1 as $v2)
           {

             $userd = $em->getRepository('UserBundle:User')->find($id);
             $userd->setlastName($v2);
             $em->persist($userd);


             ++$zl;
           }}

        $em->flush();
      }
```

I dont get any result. I am trying to get the value like this:
            $v1 =$_POST['v1']; But I dont get anything.

Can someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: are you asking how to submit a form?

Comment: I want to get the new value from  <td data-title="lastName" contenteditable='true' name="v1">{{user.lastname}}</td>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have at least two options here:

hidden fields everywhere if data (best approach):

```
<td>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkBox[]"  id="ic" value="{{ user.id }}" />
    <input type="hidden" value="{{user.lastname}}" name="v1[{{ user.id }}]"></td>
<td  data-title="id">{{user.id}}</td>
<td data-title="firstName">{{user.firstname}}</td>
<td data-title="lastName" contenteditable='true'>{{user.lastname}}</td>
```

and on serverside you do:

```
.... your code ....
foreach ($user  as $id) {
    $lastname = $v1[$id];
    ... save your lastname value ...
}
```

Anothe option is to set checkbox value with data separated by some value (ugly solution)

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="checkBox[]"  id="ic" value="{{ user.id }}#{{user.lastname}}" /></td>
            <td  data-title="id">{{user.id}}</td>
            <td data-title="firstName">{{user.firstname}}</td>
            <td data-title="lastName" contenteditable='true' name="v1">{{user.lastname}}</td>
```

**EDIT**

I see now that you are using contenteditable. You should add the value to your hidden field:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    $('input[name*="v1"]').val($(this).closest('td[name="v1"]').html());
});

<td>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkBox[]"  id="ic" value="{{ user.id }}" />
    <input type="hidden" value="{{user.lastname}}" name="v1[{{ user.id }}]"></td>
<td  data-title="id">{{user.id}}</td>
<td data-title="firstName">{{user.firstname}}</td>
<td data-title="lastName" contenteditable='true' name="v1">{{user.lastname}}</td>
```

Comment: Thanks. I am getting the previous value I dont get the editing value :/

Comment: Edited. You need to populate your hidden field with new data before submit your form.